# Новичок в bootstrap, есть пара проблем

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

решил читься верстать на bootstrap, но сразу возникло пару проблем.

```css
body {
    
}
.header {
    background-image: url(../images/header.png); !important
}
.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); !important
}
.navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family: Oswald;
}
.collapse {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav-link {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: white;
}
.nav-link:hover {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 35%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bouncy</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Hello <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

1. получаются очень некрасивые borderы при наведении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. когда размер браузера сужается до sm не видно кнопки button для открытия меню, хотя она есть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. не доходит до меня как выровнять элементы меню по центру (всмысле к чему применять свойства css)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. и опять же страшные бордеры которые занимают всю ширину а не по размеру содержимого, что смотрится отвратительно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вопросы в принципе, по вёрстке, а потом уже bootstrap, имхо

Comment: в том то и дело что на чистом html и css у меня все идеально и красиво. но вот с bootstrap какая-то дичь выходит